# Is a 56k fax modem different from a regular dial up modem?

Tags: dial-up, fax

The title says enough, is a 56k fax modem different from a regular dial up modem? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dial-up modems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dial-up_Internet_access) may be at different speeds, e.g. 14.4 kb, 56 kb etc. These modems may *also* have the capability to send fax documents, e.g. to medical services or restaurants that still use fax. A 56k fax modem is a particular specification.

This [example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008RZTJC0) claims to support "USB 56K Voice Fax Data External V.90 V.92 Modem" standards. **N.B.** telco services in various countries have [differing standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_plug), so be sure the modem works in your location.

Answer (score -1):

A fax modem may have additional hardware/software to enable you to fax to a fax machine.  For internet connection use they are identical.